# PHP storing data in an array and read them

Tags: php, android

I have a SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT speed, distance from result where id='".$ids."'";

$b = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

i want to show all speed and distance records of this user, which has been done by using

```
if ($b->num_rows >0){
  while ($row = $b->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "speed: " . $row["speed"]. " - Distance: " . $row["distance"]. "<br>";
  }
}
```

But my purpose is to store all records into an array, and then use json to send them to my android phone. just like :

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array();

array_push($result, array(
"totalTime"=>$res['totalTime'],
"totalDis"=>$res['totalDis']
));

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

i want to know how to do this with the records of speed and distance.

Comment: `while ($row = $b->fetch_assoc()) { $result[] = $row; } echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: hey man, your code is working good, post it as answer pls!

Comment: You can check one of existing answers: substantially are the same! :) Thank you for the appreciation.

Comment: Irrelevant question: Why not use a prepared statement? It's a very very small change: `$sql = "SELECT speed, distance from result where id=?;` then `$b = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql)->bind_param('i',$id)->execute();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just modify your code

```
$data=array();//declare array 
if ($b->num_rows >0){
  while ($row = $b->fetch_assoc()){
   array_push($data,$row);//strore each row to array
  }
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: “Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function” (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT speed, distance from result where id='".$ids."'";

$b = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
$result = array();
if ($b->num_rows >0){
   while ($row = $b->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($result, $row);
  }
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

Comment: “Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function” (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)